# Unable to write character from jquery keyboard via an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keyboard

***functionality:***

Have made use of images from image filepath(lib/image/keyboard/0.png) to create a jquery keyboard which will allow user to click. Hence, when user click on the respective image, the character that the image represent will be displayed within the  fieldbox.

***issue:***

When i clicked on the image keyboard, i am unable to set the character. I am unable to reference the character to the keyboard image clicked. Hence, for example, in a mobile numpad inspired keyboard:

When I click on the image of: (lib/image/keyboard/0.png)-> it should show character 0 in the input text fieldbox and when I click on the image of :(lib/image/keyboard/4.png)-> it should show the character 4 in the input text fieldbox.

But at this point, I am unable to achieve that.

***Code:***

```js
var cursorPos = 0;
var shift = false,
  capslock = false;
var $write;


//Keyboard functionality

$('#mobile_keyboard li').off('click').on('click', function() {
console.log("click");
idleTime = 0;

var $this = $(this),
  character = $this.html(); // If it's a lowercase letter, nothing happens to this variable
console.log("character:" + character);


// Delete
if ($this.hasClass('delete')) {
  var html = $write.val();

  $write.val(html.substr(0, html.length - 1));
  return false;
}

// Clear
if ($this.hasClass('clear')) {
  var html = $write.val();

  $write.val("");
  return false;
}

// Special characters
if ($this.hasClass('symbol')) character = $('span:visible', $this).html();
if ($this.hasClass('space')) character = ' ';
if ($this.hasClass('tab')) character = "\t";
if ($this.hasClass('return')) character = "\n";

// Add the character
//$write.val($write.val() + character);

var inputValue = $write.val();
textBefore = inputValue.substring(0, cursorPos);
textAfter = inputValue.substring(cursorPos, inputValue.length);

$write.val(textBefore + character + textAfter);
cursorPos += character.length;
});
}
});
```

```css
/* Keyboard_receipt CSS*/

.keyboard_receipt {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.keyboard_receipt li {
  font-size: 35px;
  float: left;
  margin: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
  padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #765725;
  background-image: url("../lib/image/mobilekeypad.png");
  background-repeat: none;
  /*border: 1px solid #000;*/
  /*-moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;*/
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<table align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="1920" top="550px">
  <tr style="height: 1080;">
    <td width="1920">

      <!-- mobile keyboard -->

      <ul class="keyboard_receipt" id="mobile_keyboard" style="z-index:10; position:absolute; left:1200px; top: 300px; margin:auto; color: #000;">

        <!-- mobile keyboard -->
        <li class="symbol" style="clear: left; width: 100px;"><font face="GothicBold"><span class="off"><img src ="lib/image/1.png"></span></font>
        </li>
        <li class="symbol" style="width: 100px;"><font face="GothicBold"><span class="off"><img src ="lib/image/2.png"></span></font>
        </li>
        <li class="symbol lastitem" style="width: 100px;"><font face="GothicBold"><span class="off"><img src ="lib/image/3.png"></span></font>
        </li>

        <li class="symbol" style="clear: left; width: 100px;"><font face="GothicBold"><span class="off"><img src ="lib/image/4.png"></span></font>
        </li>
        <li class="symbol" style="width: 100px;"><font face="GothicBold"><span class="off"><img src ="lib/image/5.png"></span></font>
        </li>
        <li class="symbol lastitem" style="width: 100px;"><font face="GothicBold"><span class="off"><img src ="lib/image/6.png"></span></font>
        </li>

        <li class="symbol" style="clear: left; width: 100px;"><font face="GothicBold"><span class="off"><img src ="lib/image/7.png"></span></font>
        </li>
        <li class="symbol" style="width: 100px;"><font face="GothicBold"><span class="off"><img src ="lib/image/8.png"></span></font>
        </li>
        <li class="symbol lastitem" style="width: 100px;"><font face="GothicBold"><span class="off"><img src ="lib/image/9.png"></span></font>
        </li>

        <li class="clear" style="clear: left; width: 100px;">
          <img src="lib/image/Clear.png">
        </li>
        <li class="symbol" style="width: 100px;"><font face="GothicBold"><span class="off"><img src ="lib/image/0.png"></span></font>
        </li>

        <li class="delete lastitem" style="width: 100px;">
          <img src="lib/image/Backspace.png">
        </li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/2hfEiVs4xbXKHJHE9qdP?p=catalogue

Comment: Can you pls make a jsfiddle? Plnkr runs very messy on my tablet

Comment: @Novice here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tmuf60f2/